# Why is my mysql_query returning no result?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, foreach

The coding is comming up with **Illegal string offset** for:

```
echo $row['rowa']. ' - '. $row['rowb']. ' - '. $row['rowc']. ' - '. $row['rowd']. ' - '. $row['rowe'].'<br />';

<?php

   $connection=mysqli_connect("localhost"/*hostname*/,
                              "username"/*username*/,
                              "password"/*password*/,
                              "dbname"/*database name*/);

try {
    // Setting the query and runnin it...
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM table");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
){ 
            foreach(mysqli_fetch_array($result) as $row) {
                echo $row['rowa']. ' - '. $row['rowb']. ' - '. $row['rowc']. ' - '. $row['rowd']. ' - '. $row['rowe'].'<br />';
            }
        }else{
            echo "QUERY IS NOT OKAY";
        }  // Closing the connection.
        $connection = null;
    }catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    } 

?>
```

The username, password, database and table name  are **not** the actual names used in the code.

Comment: You are mixing different database connectors: `mysql_...` and `mysqli_...` are two quite separate things. You cannot mix them, you have to decide which one to use. Since the old `mysql_...` connector has been deprecated a while ago you should go for the newer, more secure and flexible `mysqli_...` connector. Also you want to read about the advantages of "prepared statements" to prevent vulnerability to sql injection.

Comment: Is your password really `password`, the username really `username` and the dbname really `dbname`? If your answer is yes, you are the most careless programmer i have ever seen in my entire life.

Comment: `table` is a reserved word. You'll need to wrap it in backticks if you really want to use it as a table name. You'd do better to use a different table name.

Comment: @MikeW I am **not** using the actual varaiables.

Comment: You have one bracket `)` too many in `try {// Setting the query and runnin it...
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM table");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
){` change to `try {// Setting the query and runnin it...
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM table");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{` @TheOkayMan

Comment: You're also mixing `mysqli` with PDO execptions, you can't mix those.

Answer (score 3):

You're mixing `mysqli` with PDO exceptions `try/catch`, plus there's an extra bracket in your `try` block. Those two APIs do not mix.

See the comments in your code: (and the fixed code below that)

Sidenotes: You may want to change `foreach(mysqli_fetch_array($result) as $row)` to `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))`

Using `foreach(mysqli_fetch_array($result) as $row)` will produce repeated results of the rows and only the first letter from each row.

```
try {
    // Setting the query and runnin it...
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM table");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)

    ){
//  ^-- one bracket too many

            foreach(mysqli_fetch_array($result) as $row) {
                echo $row['rowa']. ' - '. $row['rowb']. ' - '. $row['rowc']. ' - '. $row['rowd']. ' - '. $row['rowe'].'<br />';
            }
        }else{
            echo "QUERY IS NOT OKAY";
        }  // Closing the connection.
        $connection = null;
    }catch(PDOException $e) { // this should be catch (Exception $e)
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Change it to this:

```
try {
    // Setting the query and runnin it...
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM `table`");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{ 
            foreach(mysqli_fetch_array($result) as $row) {
                echo $row['rowa']. ' - '. $row['rowb']. ' - '. $row['rowc']. ' - '. $row['rowd']. ' - '. $row['rowe'].'<br />';
            }
        }else{
            echo "QUERY IS NOT OKAY";
        }

}

catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Add error reporting at the top of your file(s)

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

---

**Rewrite:**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

$connection=mysqli_connect("localhost"/*hostname*/,
                          "username"/*username*/,
                          "password"/*password*/,
                          "dbname"/*database name*/);

    try {
        // Setting the query and runnin it...
        $result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM `table`");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
    { 

// use while instead of foreach
// while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                foreach(mysqli_fetch_array($result) as $row) {
                    echo $row['rowa']. ' - '. $row['rowb']. ' - '. $row['rowc']. ' - '. $row['rowd']. ' - '. $row['rowe'].'<br />';
                }
            }else{
                echo "QUERY IS NOT OKAY";
            }

    }

    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: +1 for time and effort

Answer (score 1):

instead of 
           `$result = mysql_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM table");`

use
           `$result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM table");`

instead of 
           `mysql_fetch_array($result)`

use
           `mysqli_fetch_array($result)`

Comment: I get the same error as for DhruvPathak's answer.

Comment: put foreach() in this if condition if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){ foreach(mysql_fetch_array($result) as $row){......}}

Comment: Illegal string offset I have updated the coding

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you should be using `mysqli_query` along with `mysqli_connect` and not `mysql_query`

Comment: With the 'i' the error I get is  `Illegal string offset` for line `echo $row['Name']. ' - '. $row['Club']. ' - '. $row['Level']. ' - '. $row['App']. ' - '. $row['Score'].'<br />';
`

Comment: check the names of your columns. mysqli_fetch_array() builds a mixed array with numeric and text indexes. Use mysqli_fetch_assoc() to get an associative array only so your array isn't double the size. Your columns may not be the same so your index doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
<?php
 $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "Database name");
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
  exit();
}

  // Setting the query and runnin it...
  $result = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM table");

  /* execute query */
  $result->execute();
  $result = $mysqli->get_result();

     while ($row= $result->fetch_assoc()) 
     { 

            echo $row['rowa']. ' - '. $row['rowb']. ' - '. $row['rowc']. ' - '. $row['rowd']. ' - '. $row['rowe'].'<br />';

     }


    ?>
```

Comment: `Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in``$result->execute();`

Comment: what is your table name

Comment: the table name is `score`

Comment: Are you putting any where condition in the query or using as it is ?

Comment: Fot the moment as it is; unless it will make the coding work.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, something is wrong with your connection. As mysqli* don't throw exceptions, you can't catch them.

Those functions return valid objects or FALSE, 0 or null on error. So you need to check for that.

Here is the code, that should tell you what's wrong with your communication with the DB.

```
<?php

function ctest() {
    $connection=mysqli_connect("localhost"/*hostname*/,
                               "username"/*username*/,
                               "password"/*password*/,
                               "dbname"/*database name*/);

    if($connection) {
        $result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM `table`");
        if($result) {
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {
                foreach(mysqli_fetch_array($result) as $row) {
                    echo $row['rowa']. ' - '. $row['rowb']. ' - '
                                          . $row['rowc']. ' - '
                                          . $row['rowd']. ' - '
                                          . $row['rowe'].'<br />';
                }
                return;
            }
            echo "0 rows";
            return;
        }
        echo "No result";
        return;
    }
    echo "No connection";
    $connection = null;
}
?>
```

Comment: Illegal string offset

Comment: Column names are case-sensitive. http://cn2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: Column name are correctly spelt and correct case.

Comment: It should tell you, precisely which offset is incorrect. Take it from there.